# I try find non matching word but has problem

Tags: python

I try to do

```
nonmatch = list(filter(lambda x:x not in list1, list2))
nonmatch = list(filter(lambda x:x not in nonmatch, list3))
nonmatch = list(filter(lambda x:x not in nonmatch, list4))
nonmatch = list(filter(lambda x:x not in nonmatch, list5))
```

to find non matching words and try to use Counter(list)

```
list_1 = []
for w in list1:
    if w in nonmatch:
        list_1.append(w)
print(Counter(list_1))
```

but there are still some words that are the same as other lists.

Comment: Can we a sample input you're using and the output you're getting? It might a case of not matching upper case, lower case words

Comment: My input is not English. There is no lower case and upper case